# Using Python Beautiful soup for Web scrape

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm looking to pull ASIN number from the below web pages. The ASIN numbers follow the 'data-asin' element of the HTML on amazon. I then want to print the output in the same way I have the other elements below. Thanks for your help in advance

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

def get_url(search_term):
    """Generate a url from search term"""
    template = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k={}&ref=nb_sb_noss_2'
    search_term = search_term.replace(' ','+') 
    return template.format(search_term)

url = get_url('Ultrawide monitor')

driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div',{'data-component-type': 's-search-result'})

item = results [0]

atag = item.h2.a
atag.text
description = atag.text.strip()
url = 'https//www.amazon.com'+atag.get('href')
price_parent = item.find('span', 'a-price')
price = price_parent.find('span', 'a-offscreen').text
rating = item.i.text
review_count = item.find('span', {'class': 'a-size-base', 'dir':     
'auto'}).text

print(description)
print(price)
print(rating)
print(review_count)
```

Comment: what is ASIN number? What exactly is the error you are getting? This code doesn't seem to work after the `results = soup.find_all('div',{'data-component-type': 's-search-result'})` line.

Comment: It seems to work for me.... so not sure why.

ASIN number is the product code

Comment: Ah..So you are looking to click on each item in the search list get the ASIN, Description etc?

Comment: ASIN is in the HTML of the website. Or in the 'Item' object. I can see 

data-asin="B08BYJ5BCF"

Its the reference in the speech marks i need

Comment: What's this? `atag.text` ..This does nothing. Did you want to assign it to a variable?

Comment: Also share the error you get.

Comment: Hey i dont get an error. i just cant work out how to pull that prt of the HTML. im still lerning BS, and stuck on this bit

Atag.text for something else.

Answer (score 0):

Description of problem could be improved - What I understand is that you like to get the `link text` of `h2`

**Solution**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc ='''
<div class="a-section a-spacing-none">
    <h2 class="a-size-mini a-spacing-none a-color-base s-line-clamp-2">
        <a class="a-link-normal a-text-normal" href="/Promised-Land-Barack-Obama/dp/0241491517/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&amp;keywords=%7B%7D&amp;qid=1605860574&amp;sr=8-1">
            <span class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal" dir="auto">A Promised Land</span>
        </a>
    </h2>
    <div class="a-row a-size-base a-color-secondary"><span class="a-size-base" dir="auto">by </span>
        <a class="a-size-base a-link-normal" href="/Barack-Obama/e/B001H6OA8E?ref=sr_ntt_srch_lnk_1&amp;qid=1605860574&amp;sr=8-1">
            Barack Obama
        </a>
    <span class="a-letter-space"></span><span class="a-size-base a-color-secondary" dir="auto"> | </span><span class="a-letter-space"></span><span class="a-size-base a-color-secondary a-text-normal" dir="auto">17 Nov 2020</span></div>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
```

Select the `a` of `h2`:

```
atag = soup.select('h2 > a')
print(atag[0].text)
```

May this help you - Let us know or try to descripe your problem more detailed.